# Redundancy in the definition of monotonically increasing functions

Tags: definition, monotone-functions

[This popular Algorithms book](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms-third-edition) tells us the following definition of monotonically increasing functions:

> A function $f(n)$ is ***monotonically increasing*** if $m \le n$ implies $f(m) \le f(n)$.

I can see why we need $m < n \implies f(m) \le f(n)$ but I am having a hard time understanding why we need to write $m \le n$ instead of just $m < n$. Isn't it kind of redundant because $m = n \implies f(m) = f(n)$ is already true because that's what makes $f(n)$ a "function" in the first place?

So re-writing the above definition:

> A function $f(n)$ is ***monotonically increasing*** if $m < n$ implies $f(m) \le f(n)$.

Is this not sufficient? Or am I missing something?

Comment: One good reason is that $\leq$ is a partial order and $<$ is not. The first definition can thus be extended to maps between partially ordered sets, which are a pretty common structure:

 **Definition:** A map $f:X\to Y$ between partially ordered sets $(X,\leq_X)$ and $(Y,\leq_Y)$ is said to be *monotonically increasing* if $f(m)\leq_Y f(n)$ whenever $m\leq_X n$.

Comment: the m<=n ist not necessary, but since- as you say it is the anyway , it does not matter if you have the  = in it or not.

Comment: @MPW I think you are correct.